# File/media exists on folder but throw error 404 - WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a website using wordpress, after a migration of domain ("I changed the code from the domain.com.br to test.domain.com.br) The media files is not showing properly(404).

I've tried to change files permission, change permalinks on wordpress and deleted and created the .htaccess file, nothing worked.

The weird stuff is that the file is in the correct path.

Here is the shown error on network tab:
 https://i.ibb.co/vHV4bXm/erropng.png
How the images looks like on media menu:
 https://i.ibb.co/J3KBGJ2/midia.png
The images on the properly folder in ftp:
 https://i.ibb.co/s34MGXB/ftp.png

Comment: How did you migrate ? Did you replace all occurence of the old domain url with the new domain url ? If not, install https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ and do a search and replace of your old domain url by your new domain url.

Comment: Yes I've replaced. If I upload a new image the same thing happens,isn't only the old ones.

Comment: Can you try to go to settings -> permalink and save ?

Comment: I've tried , not worked :(

Comment: And you file permission ?

Comment: All of the files is set to 0755

Comment: It's weird beca this url is 404 while it shouldn't http://teste.volvox.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/

Comment: Check you htaccess

Comment: my htaccess: https://pastebin.com/dhys3esj

Comment: I see you are using WebP Express. There might be a conflict with it, try to deactivate this plugin to see if it fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the permision of the files. It's solved now.